# is it true that some coffee types contain elephants dung?

Tags: coffee-culture

As you can see in this post of the [Telegraph](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/foodanddrink/foodanddrinkpicturegalleries/9737226/Elephant-dung-coffee-Black-Ivory-beans-passed-through-the-animals-guts.html)

> In the lush hills of northern Thailand, a herd of 20 elephants is
>   excreting some of the world's most expensive coffee. Trumpeted as
>   earthy in flavour and smooth on the palate, the exotic new brew is
>   made from beans eaten by Thai elephants and plucked a day later from
>   their dung. A gut reaction inside the elephant creates what its
>   founder calls the coffee's unique taste.

Is this in fact real?

[image: elephant]

Comment: have you tried skeptics.stackexchange.com?

Comment: Elephant.. Monkey..  I have in fact seen a bag of this stuff.. the guys who bought it have the bag displayed lol.. This is the same concept as kopi luwak which is much more well known.  So.. This is real!  That being said, the post title is a bit deceiving.  The digestive juices are used to break down the coffee bean.  I'm sure they are well washed and subsequently roasted which would to a lot toward sterilizing etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is real.  You need go to Cambodia for a good cup of monkey coffee. Philippine coffee is the best. Just plain mountain grown. Cambodian bay is a good coffee. A more flat ground seamisted coffee. Were grown. I would avoid the elephant coffee & monkey.

Comment: Could you provide some reference points to back up your statements?

Comment: Personal.  Live in the Philippines. But in America now as lived close to the war zone. Refuge right now.  But when in Cambodia late last year drinking Cambodia bay coffee I found it very good. It will soon be exported I think. There bay coffee. Also go to Thailand some.  So travel & taste myself is my reference on coffee from Asia.

Answer (score 4):

This is actually called [black ivory coffee](https://www.blackivorycoffee.com/about).

Cambodia is not actually where you get this coffee *originally*. The company that creates this coffee is actually based in Thailand and uses coffee beans and elephants in Thailand to make this weird sounding coffee. As said by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Ivory_Coffee):

> Black Ivory Coffee is a brand of coffee produced by the Black Ivory Coffee Company Ltd in northern Thailand from Arabica coffee beans consumed by elephants and collected from their waste

A simple [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=elephant+dung+coffee&oq=elep&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0j35i39j0l3.2405j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) brings up a lot of results on black ivory coffee where your Telegraph article comes up as the first result. **Thus, this does exist and is not a hoax.**